# Any other option to find iOS 7 UDID?

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics, ios7, flurry, udid

I would like to know about how to overcome with `iOS 7 udid issue`.

What we have tried: we have already implemented `vendorUniqueID`, well as Apple suggested it will be changed once user uninstall the app, thus is not good option.

Advertisement unique id is not an option; as Apple suggested that it is recommended to use for advertisement purpose only. As our app is not advertisement showcase app.

What we need know: we already have restoration id, is there a way to `store that restoration ID` such that it can be retrieved once the application is reinstalled.

I was wondering how the Google analytic' and Flurry analytic' are tracking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by performing following steps.

1) #import `<Security/Security.h>` in your project.

2) Save your detail to keychain using **SecItemAdd** method.

```
-(void) saveUsername:(NSString*)user withPassword:(NSString*)pass forServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSecClassInternetPassword,  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, nil];

    // Remove any old values from the keychain
    OSStatus err = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef) dict);

    // Create dictionary of parameters to add
    NSData* passwordData = [pass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    dict = [NSDictionary kSecClassInternetPassword, kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, passwordData, kSecValueData, user, kSecAttrAccount, nil];

    // Try to save to keychain
    err = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) dict, NULL);

}
```

3) Get Stored data from keychain even if you have deleted an application.

```
-(void) getCredentialsForServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSecClassInternetPassword,  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, nil];

    // Look up server in the keychain
    NSDictionary* found = nil;
    OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) dict, (CFDictionaryRef*) &found);
    if (!found) return;

    // Found
    NSString* user = (NSString*) [found objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
    NSString* pass = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[found objectForKey:kSecValueData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIAlertView * alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Key found" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user : %@ pass :%@",user,pass] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [alertView show];
    NSLog(@"user %@ : pass  %@", user,pass);

}
```

4) If you want to delete this attribute dictionary from keychain you can do that.

```
-(void) removeAllCredentialsForServer:(NSString*)server {

    // Create dictionary of search parameters
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSecClassInternetPassword,  kSecClass, server, kSecAttrServer, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData, nil];

    // Remove any old values from the keychain
    OSStatus err = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef) dict);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Any information you store into the keychain will be restored even if the app is deleted.

Comment: I noticed this a while back. Is there any documentation on this behavior?  I just assumed it was a defect given that it circumvents the tracking prevention goal.

Comment: Not sure. It has been like this for a long time but you'd need to search / read the keychain docs to find explicit references.

Comment: I searched, answered and implemented after you answered here. Thanks.